# Dynamically assign variables in batch

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am trying to assign from dynamically given result new variables. Script currently dynamically counts and echoes drive letters from "wmic logicaldisk get name /value" given result
it does successfully echoing drive letter, which I would like to be assigned as new variables for example:
C should be assigned as %C% variable or %DRIVE-C% variable. Thanks You, 
Here is the script:

`````
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "output_cnt=0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:=" %%f in ('wmic logicaldisk get name /value') do (
    set /a output_cnt+=1
    set "DRIVE[!output_cnt!]=%%f"
)

for /L %%n in (1 1 !output_cnt!) DO echo Partition !DRIVE[%%n]!````
`````

Comment: Well, what is your question?

Comment: To assign echoed result to variable, in this case drive letters, for example c to %c%, d to %d%.

Comment: Your provided code is attempting to define variables named, for example, `%DRIVE[1]%`, `%DRIVE[2]%` etc. but your question is asking to define them like this, `%DRIVE-C%`, or this, `%C%`, where `C` is representative of the first character of the returned `Name` property. Can you please clarify exactly which variable format you need to define? Beyond that you appear to be trying to somehow link these variables with partitions. Can you please explain what exactly you're tring to achieve with your task, instead of just part of it? There may be a better way of achieving the intended goal.

Comment: The answer you've accepted confirms that neither of the variable names you mentioned in your question was what you wanted, `%DRIVE[C]%` wasn't one of your provided options! Regardless of that, I'm a little bit confused by that sort of naming strategy. What is the purpose of defining variables whose names always contain, in an identifiable way, the value string? You should never need to know the content of `%DRIVE[C]%` because you must have known it in order to use the variable which contains it. Even possibly using `If Defined Drive[C]`, would have no benefit over an `If Exist` type command.

Comment: Are you therefore trying to determine if a drive letter which was assigned is no longer assigned, or vice versa? i.e perhaps a USB has been removed or added during the running of your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe you're asking how to assign values to an array using the drive letter as an index, correct?

```bat
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set AvDrives=
For /f "tokens=2 delims=:=" %%f in ('wmic logicaldisk get name /value') do (
::: - Build a reference string containing the drives returned to use as the Array index.
    Set AvDrives=!AvDrives! "%%~f"
::: - Assign a value to the Array index - optional
    Set "DRIVE[%%~f]=%%~f"
)

::: - Iterate over / perform actions on the array indices
For %%D in (!AvDrives!) Do Echo 'DRIVE[%%~D]=%%~D'

pause
```

Output:

```
'DRIVE[C]=C'
'DRIVE[D]=D'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Looking into a code and a requirement, I´ve realized that it sets two or more values in one array. Is it possible to set each value to it´s own variable using a loop? For example when find C to set %C%, next hop when find D to set %D%?
Thanks

Comment: What your asking here is a tad unclear, - if only one drive is found, only one value will be set. do you mean  to manually input a value for each drive when found, or to assign a known value to each drive? Please update your question with an example of what output you're expecting with each use.

Comment: If all you need is to set C=C, D=D, then: `Set "%%~f=%%~f"